# ggplot2 fill legend does not display the correct "fill" color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am confused of this problem for a long time. A simple data frame is constructed as follows

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = 5:1,
  fill = c(rep("pink", 3), rep("blue", 2)),
  shape = c(rep(21, 3), rep(22, 2))
)
```

Suppose I wand to show the legend of the fill

```
uniFill <- unique(data$fill)
p <- ggplot(data,
       mapping = aes(x = x,
                     y = y,
                     fill = fill)) + 
  geom_point(shape = data$shape) + 
  # show legend so that I do not call `scale_fill_identity()`
  scale_fill_manual(values = uniFill,
                    labels = uniFill,
                    breaks = uniFill)
p
```

The graphics are OK, however, the legend is not correct

[image]

I guess, maybe different shapes (21 to 25) cannot be merged? Then, I partition the data into two subsets where the first set has shape 21 and the second has shape 22.

```
data1 <- data[1:3, ]
data2 <- data[4:5, ]
# > data1$shape
# [1] 21 21 21
# > data2$shape
# [1] 22 22
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x,
                     y = y,
                     fill = fill)) + 
  geom_point(data = data1, shape = data1$shape) + 
  geom_point(data = data2, shape = data2$shape) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = uniFill,
                    labels = uniFill,
                    breaks = uniFill)
```

Unfortunately, the legend does not change. Then, I changed the shape from a vector to a scalar, as in

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x,
                     y = y,
                     fill = fill)) + 
  geom_point(data = data1, shape = 21) + 
  geom_point(data = data2, shape = 22) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = uniFill,
                    labels = uniFill,
                    breaks = uniFill)
```

The legend of the fill color is correct finally...

[image]

So what happens here? Is it a bug? Is it possible to just add a single layer but with different shapes (21 to 25)?

A possible solution is that one can add component `guides()`, as in

```
p + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = uniFill,
                                                 shape = 21)))
```

But I am more interested in why `p` does not work (legend)

Comment: Technically this is a bug: See here: <https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2322>

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is very difficult to fix

Answer (score 6):

The main reason your legend is not working in your first example is because you did not put your shape in the aesthetics.

I have a couple other suggestions:  Do not define colors in your data frame; instead define a column to change the aesthetics using a code.  Then define your fill and shape values explicitly.  Each of the scales needs to have the same name - in this case "Legend."

Give this edit a try.

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = 5:1,
  fill = c(rep("p", 3), rep("b", 2))
 )

uniFill <- c("p"="pink", "b"="blue")
uniShape <- c("p" = 21, "b" = 22)

p <- ggplot(data,
            mapping = aes(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          fill = fill,
                          shape = fill)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  # show legend so that I do not call `scale_fill_identity()`
  scale_fill_manual("Legend",values = uniFill,
                    labels = uniFill)+
  scale_shape_manual("Legend",values = uniShape,
                     labels = uniFill)
p
```

(edit) If your fill and shape aesthetics do not match up, I don't see any other way than to use `guides` and two legends. Notice that if your attribute column is descriptive, you do not need to set the labels and your code will be cleaner (see shape vs fill aesthetics).

```
data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = 5:1,
  fill = c(rep("p", 3), rep("b", 2)),
  shape = c(rep("circles", 2), rep("squares", 3))
)

uniFill <- c("p"="pink", "b"="blue")
uniShape <- c("circles" = 21, "squares" = 22)

p <- ggplot(data,
            mapping = aes(x = x,
                          y = y,
                          fill = fill,
                          shape = shape)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  # show legend so that I do not call `scale_fill_identity()`
  scale_fill_manual("Legend fill",values = uniFill,
                    labels = uniFill)+
  scale_shape_manual("Legend shape",values = uniShape  )+
  guides(fill = guide_legend("Legend fill", override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
p
```

[image: point plot with two legends]

Comment: Thanks! Very Cool. Well, what if the shape and fill does not match? For example, `data <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = 5:1,
  fill = c(rep("p", 3), rep("b", 2)),
  shape = c(rep("a", 2), rep("d", 3))
)`. Thanks again for your time and patience.